# How does require function work in CasperJS and PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, require, casperjs

I am a newbie in JavaScript. I have been reading PhantomJS and CasperJS API. All the time I see the following line of code

in CasperJS

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
```

in PhantomJS

```
var webPage = require('webpage').create();
```

We can replace the above lines with

in CasperJS

```
var casper = new require('casper').Casper()
```

in PhantomJS

```
var WebPage = require('webpage');
var webPage = new WebPage();
```

Based on what I know, CasperJS is testing utility sit on top of PhantomJS environment. I'm guessing that the `require` function has the same underlying implementation for both CasperJS and PhantomJS.

I have been search around for the API reference to the `require` function, but I couldn't find any.

Would be nice if someone can guide me to the right path.

1. What does the `require` function do? (is it similar to the functionality of `using` keyword in C# .net)
2. Where does PhantomJS reference the "require" function from? (is it using its own implementation or is it referencing another javascript framework?)

Comment: It is best to stick to the `.create()` type initialization, because additional checks are performed there which ensure that the script functions properly.

Comment: Yes thanks everyone. The other thread got my confusion clear. Thank you